# ld -Ttext produces an executable with 64KB of padding

Tags: gcc, arm, ld, elf

I'm trying to specify the address of the .text section of a 64 bit ARMv8 ELF using the linker argument -Ttext=

It does what I need it to and produces a .text section with correct references to .data

```
ld -Ttext=40000000 -Tdata=40001000 main.o
objdump -h a.out
a.out:     file format elf64-littleaarch64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000278  0000000040000000  0000000040000000  00010000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000004  0000000040001000  0000000040001000  00011000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .comment      0000003a  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00011004  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

The problem I have with this is the file offset. Why does ld put blow up the file that should be less than 4KB and put .text at 64K? It's not a problem once it gets loaded to main memory - but storage on disk could become problematic.

Is there a command line option to prevent this?

edit: so it looks like the program segment is aligned to 0x10000 - I don't see an option to adjust this alignment. Maybe a linker script is my only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [option `-n` or `--nmagic`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> Turn off page alignment of sections, and disable linking against shared libraries. 
>   If the output format supports Unix style magic numbers, mark the output as "NMAGIC".